# Best way of modelling a list within a component in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Imagine I have a property site which lets you enquire to different estate agents about a given property. Different enquiry methods might have different billing calculations associated with them, and not all agents will have every billing model enabled.

```
public class EmailEnquiryBillingModel : ValueObject
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPerEnquiry { get; set; }
}

public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Monday,
    Tuseday,
    // etc.
}

public class OpeningHours : ValueObject
{
    public DateTime OpeningTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClosingTime { get; set;} 
}

public class PhoneEnquiryBillingModel : ValueObject
{
    public PhoneEnquiryBillingModel()
    {
        OpeningHours = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, OpeningHours>();
    }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<DayOfWeek, OpeningHours> OpeningHours { get; set; }
}

public class EstateAgent : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EmailEnquiryBillingModel EmailEnquiryBillingModel { get; set; }
    public PhoneEnquiryBillingModel PhoneEnquiryBillingModel { get; set; }
}
```

NHibernate has semantics with components (value objects) whereby if every property in a component is null, the component will also be null.

Therefore, with the appropriate mapping, you can write `if(estateAgent.EmailEnquiryBillingModel  != null)` rather than having to check every individual property of the email enquiry billing model, or whether the model is valid: we either have the model or we don't. It's a simple, elegant way of checking if a particular billing model is enabled.

The problem comes when you have a set within a component, such as with the phone enquiry billing model and the various opening hours. Neither the `PhoneEnquiryBillingModel` nor the `OpeningHours` are entities. These are legitimate value objects: we don't care whether the estate agent is open from *this* 9am on Monday or *that* 9am on a Monday, just that it opens at 9am on a Monday.

Therefore, this feels like the semantically correct way of representing this domain model in C#.

However, the fact that the `PhoneEnquiryBillingModel` contains a set (of `ProviderOpenHours`), and a set cannot be null in NHibernate, only empty, means that `ProviderOpenHours` will always be non-null, even if the estate agent doesn't meaningfully have that enquiry model enabled. (For more info, see: https://ayende.com/blog/4685/those-are-the-rules-even-when-you-dont-like-them).

This means that you can't do a simple check like `if(estateAgent.PhoneEnquiryBillingModel != null)`, because that object is *always* not-null.

Therefore, for some billing models you'd be able to do a null check to see if they are enabled, but for other billing models you'd have to find an alternative way of checking, depending on whether those billing models contain a set.

Effectively, you'd need to know the *internal structure* of a billing model to know if you could do that kind of comparison, which feels like you're breaking encapsulation and changing your domain model based on the rules of the ORM.

Is there a better way of modelling this? Or a way to get NHibernate to serialize in the `PhoneEnquiryBillingModel` as null, if it doesn't have a phone number or any opening hours?

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, with the appropriate mapping, you can write
> if(estateAgent.EmailEnquiryBillingModel  != null)

This would not be the best encapsulation in itself.

Instead, you go for:

```
if (estateAgent.DoesAcceptEmailEnquiries())
```

and

```
if (estateAgent.DoesAcceptPhoneEnquiries())
```

This would give better encapsulation than interrogating properties on the EstageAgent aggregate to make an assumption about the EstateAgent's capabilities.  What if you decided to change the implementation of how an EstateAgent stored this information internally?  You need to change all clients.

There's nothing *particularly* bad about an EstateAgent performing individual property checks on its underlying value objects.

However, you could go further and implement a checker method on the PhoneEnquiryBillingModel, perhaps even static to avoid the null check in EstateAgent.

**PhoneEnquiryBillingModel**

```
public class PhoneEnquiryBillingModel : ValueObject
{
    public PhoneEnquiryBillingModel()
    {
        OpeningHours = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, OpeningHours>();
    }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<DayOfWeek, OpeningHours> OpeningHours { get; set; }

    public static bool DoesAcceptEnquiries(PhoneEnquiryBillingModel phone)
    {
        if (phone == null) return false;

        if (phone.OpeningHours.Count == 0) return false;
 
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Estate Agent**

```
public class EstateAgent : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EmailEnquiryBillingModel _emailEnquiryBillingModel { get; set; }
    public PhoneEnquiryBillingModel _phoneEnquiryBillingModel { get; set; }

    public bool DoesAcceptPhoneEnquiries()
    {
        return PhoneEnquiryBillingModel.DoesAcceptEnquiries(
            _phoneEnquiryBillingModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I can see that's a solution. But I don't think it's uncommon to have optional fields, where if the field exists you assume you have a valid property and perform some logic using that property; and if it's null then it's not applicable and you do something else.

What having separate logic to check existence and validity (if phone != null && phone.OpeningHours.Count > 0) then it adds more work?

Also, the client programmer might not know they have to check the DoesAcceptPhoneEnquiries() method before accessing the PhoneEnquiryBillingModel object.

Comment: Encapsulate!  Should the client really be accessing the PhoneEnquiryBillingModel if it doesn't know what to do with it and when?  Your model is anemic.  Your client is simply navigating data structures in classes.  That's not DDD.  Yes, it's more work in the model, but easier for the client.  If the model is less work, then the client needs to do more work and know more about the model than they really should need to.

Comment: I see your point. But I think there might be some contexts in which the client programmer might want to know about the business model. Let's say you have a billing service, which takes in a property and a billing model, and works out how much an enquiry about that property should cost, e.g. billingService.GetCostOfEnquiry(property, enquiryBillingModel). In which case, I don't think the billing model should need to be encapsulated within the estate agent entity. The billing service only cares about the billing model. The other properties of the estate agent are irrelevant in that calculation.

Comment: In your example: GetCostOfEnquiry, the client is still not examining the properties of the enquiryBillingModel, so that's fine.  You don't have to "hide" the billing model behind the estate agent ... if you put behaviour on the billing model that the client can use.  The point is, the client should be invoking behaviour on your model, not enumerating its properties to decide what to do with it.  That would mean your client is implementing business logic that belongs in your domain model